# How to enable https in react app created with npx command on deployed on Google cloud. Need to use certificates purchased from Godaddy

Tags: reactjs, ssl, google-cloud-platform, debian-based, godaddy-api

We have developed website in react, first step react app is created using npx command.
This react is deployed on Google cloud, everything is working fine when deployed on 80 port.
We are facing issue when we want to convert http to https. We have purchased SSL certificates from godaddy and want to use them to convert from http to https.

Help us solve this, if you are already done this.

Answer (score 0):

in Google Cloud Platform there are two ways for enabling SSL certificates (managed SSL certificates by Google and signed by Let's Encrypt or your own SSl certificate as in your case):

1- Managed SSL certificates by Google is provisioned automaticaly. to make sure just check in the console by going to **App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains**, check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#verify_a_managed_certificate_has_been_provisioned).

2- Your own SSL(your case): check this [fully detailed instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#using_your_own_ssl_certificates).

In both cases make sure that your custom domain is already [mapped to your application and you have configured your DNS record](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains)